# margin-top and position: sticky in Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge, sticky

I'm trying to create a sticky header and noticed that in Edge the header's margin is doubled for some reason.

**UPDATED**
Here is the URL on full page example
https://codepen.io/galuka/full/qBZJOeJ

**UPDATED 2**
It looks like new Microsoft Edge based on Chromium works OK, so issue appears only on non-Chromium Edge versions.

Here is a simplified example of the issue:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
}
.sticky {
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky">
    Here goes sticky header
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
  </div>
 </div>
```

In Chrome and Firefox it works as expected, but in Edge the margin looks like 160px rather than 80px.

I also noticed that the issue can be fixed if I add any positive padding to the container class, for example 1px.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
.sticky {
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky">
    Here goes sticky header
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
  </div>
 </div>
```

I'm quite new to CSS, so if anybody can explain this behaviour, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Both of your examples appear to be lacking sufficient height for the sticky element to actually take effect. Do you have more code or content that you can add to the snippets to make the problem more apparent?

Comment: @TylerH I have added the URL to the full page example so it would have enough content for sticky behaviour, it you think this is important for the question

Comment: I try to test the issue with the MS Edge legacy browser and with the other browser. I can see that the Edge legacy browser leaving more space at the top than other browsers. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/Iwr0Lmq) It looks like some issue with the Edge legacy browser. I suggest you press the ALT + J key in the Edge legacy browser and try to provide feedback to Microsoft regarding this issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers implement some default styles via a CSS file called User Agent Style Sheet. To ensure consistency across different browsers, you should add a small rule at the top of your CSS file. The code zeros out margins and padding ensuring consistency:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

As you stated that adding a padding solved the problem, this is definitely the solution. Furthermore you can right-click on any element on a webpage and choose `inspect element` and you would be able to see all the CSS applied to that element.

Comment: I have included normalize.css, so I believe it shouldn't be the case